# How to Implement an Attended Transfer with pjsip 2.3 in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, pjsip, freeswitch

In my VOIP application I need to implement call transfer functionality. It's working with `pjsua_call_xfer(*call_id, &pj_uri, NULL)` , this is blind transfer.

But according to my requirement I need to implement attended transfer with `pjsua_call_xfer_replaces(call, dst_call, PJSUA_XFER_NO_REQUIRE_REPLACES, NULL)`.

Attended Call Transfer:

1. During a call, press the “Transfer” button (the active call is placed on hold).
2. After speaking with the second party, press the “Transfer” button again to complete the transfer.
   Transfer may be canceled during establishment by pressing the Cancel soft key. The original call is resumed.
3. Place a call to the number to which you want to transfer the call.

For this I'm doing like below,

During a call I'm holding the current call and dialing to new party, after successful connecting new party I'm refering like below.

`pjsua_call_xfer_replaces(<first call id>, <second call id>, PJSUA_XFER_NO_REQUIRE_REPLACES, NULL)`

Is this correct way!!! or Am I missing any thing???

What is the procedure to achieve attended transfer in PJSIP 2.3 in iOS. Can any one help!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the solution bro??

Comment: I tried a lot, unfortunately that feature was dropped in that product. Might be in version 2.5 pjsip added some APIs, refer the latest document